# I am trying to use an IF statement to check a cell for 20 different variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to check a cell for a word or series of words. There are about 20 different versions I am looking for and if it is one of those, then I want to do nothing. If it isn't one of those, then I want it to be blank. I have it worked out to work correctly for one specific item, but how can I make it to look for the 20 different items without doing 20 IF statements? Would I be able to make an array or something for the IF statement? I don't really know how to do that either but I could look it up.

Here is what I have for my one specific statement:

```
 ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
    If (LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "A").Value) = "transfer" And _
        Not InStr(1, LCase(Range("B" & lngRow)), LCase("err")) <> 0) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "B").Value = ""

    End If
```

I need to do that but for 20 other words. This one is searching if it has err in any cell for the word Error.

Comment: Yes, you could load the items into an array (perhaps from a column in a worksheet) and then search for each cell's value in the array. Chip Pearson has a lot of good information and sample code for working with arrays: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of search terms and loop through that array. I've used a variant array for ease:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim arr As Variant, v As Variant

    arr = Array("err", "err2", "err3") 'all 20 in here or get from worksheet as per below
    'arr = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")) 

    For Each v In arr
        'IF statement in this loop, using the variable v rather than the string "err"
        'MsgBox v
    Next v
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured using something like an array might work but I am not very familiar with them and not too sure how to use them. But I think I will try to get this to work so I can get more familiar with it. Thanks again! I will mark complete if this works!

Comment: @Robillard, no problem - happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`elseif` allows you to add additional conditions to one `if` statement.  It would be cleaner to loop through an array, but this is how you would do it with `elseif` for your information.

Here is some generic code.  If you do not include `else` at the end, then it will do nothing if none of the conditions are met.

```
Sub test_elseif()

If x = 1 Then
   y = 1
ElseIf x = 2 Then
    y = 2
ElseIf x = 3 Then
    y = 3
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome yeah I believe that would work. But I think I might try to get the other answer using an array to work. I am not very familiar with arrays and I should probably learn them.

Comment: @Robillard I agree 100%!  I just wanted to let you know of this basic way of doing it.  This would probably be a better way if there are less than 5 conditions or so.

Comment: Yeah I actually ended up using an array and also using a IF, ElseIf statement because I had to check if it was (A and C) or (B and C) basically. When C was 15 different words. So i think that was probably the easiest way. So if I had to check like A, B, D, E, F and so on to like 20 times, checking if it was one of those, and one of the 20 C options, I could probably do an array to search the other array correct? Just wondering for future use if you can understand what I meant there : )

Comment: Very cool! Using the array was not as hard as I thought it would be.

Comment: @Robillard Awesome! I'm glad to hear that. I would encourage you to explore arrays and collections in depth.  They can make you a much more powerful VBA programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Create in sheet the range named "myWords" with the testing words.
Then in vba code refers to it in another loop:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("myWords")

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
  For Each cell In rng

    If (LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "A").Value) _
        = cell And _
        Not InStr(1, LCase(Range("B" & lngRow)), LCase("err")) <> 0) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "B").Value = ""
    End If
  Next cell
```

Comment: I got it working using an array and a IF, ELSEIF statement because I had to check two different columns, but I wasn wondering what you meant by creating in a sheet a range named myWords? What do you mean by that?

Comment: A name is a meaningful shorthand that makes it easier to understand the purpose of a cell reference (range with data you are using to test). [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)